# reactjs - Formik form does not fire submit on return key press

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I have the following form written in React using Formik:

```
import React, { FunctionComponent } from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { object, string } from 'yup';
import { Formik, FormikActions, Field, FormikProps } from 'formik';
import SimpleInput from './Fields/SimpleInput';
import FieldError from './Fields/FieldError';

interface FormValues {
  email: string;
  password: string;
}
interface OwnProps {
  onSubmit: (data: FormValues) => any;
}

const validationSchema = object().shape({
  email: string()
    .email('Please enter a valid email address')
    .required('Email is a required field'),
  password: string()
    .min(8)
    .required('Password is a required field'),
});

type Props = OwnProps;

const LoginForm: FunctionComponent<Props> = ({ onSubmit }) => {
  const initialValues = {
    email: '',
    password: '',
  };

  const onFormSubmit = async (values: FormValues, { setSubmitting }: FormikActions<FormValues>) => {
    await onSubmit(values);
    setSubmitting(false);
  };

  return (
    <Formik
      onSubmit={onFormSubmit}
      initialValues={initialValues}
      validationSchema={validationSchema}
      render={({ handleSubmit, isSubmitting }: FormikProps<FormValues>) => (
        <form className="ipx-form sign" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <h1>Sign in</h1>
          <div className="ipx-register-here">
            ( Don&#39;t have an account? ) &nbsp;
            <NavLink to="/register">Register here</NavLink>
          </div>
          <br />
          <Field name="email" type="email" component={SimpleInput} label="Email Address" placeholder="Email" />
          <FieldError name="email" />
          <br />
          <br />
          <div className="fields">
            <Field name="password" type="password" component={SimpleInput} label="Password" placeholder="Password" />
            <FieldError name="password" />
          </div>
          <br />
          Forgot <NavLink to="/forgot-password">password?</NavLink>
          <br />
          <button className="button ipx-submit-button" id="ipx-login-submit" type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>
            <span className="ladda-label">Sign in</span>
          </button>
        </form>
      )}
    />
  );
};

export default LoginForm;
```

Which works fine if I click the button to submit the form (it dispatches the Redux action and logs the user in), however when I try to submit the form with a Return/Enter key press it fails to catch the event. I tried logging the event in the `onSubmit` prop of the `<form>` element but no event is triggered on Enter press at all. This same form was previously written using `redux-form` and the Return key functionality worked as it should.

I initially thought it might be due to the asynchronous form handling but I switched to a regular synchronous function and it did not work as well.

Has anyone ever experienced something similar, and if so, please share any fixes.

Thank you!

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/r4xzw0m1wn)

Comment: You are sure validation pass and fields are not empty?

Comment: @dfsq Yes, the form submits properly if I click the Submit button with the mouse pointer. Only Enter does not work. The event does not trigger at all.

I tried logging the event in the `onSubmit` prop of the form and it doesn't log anything at all when I press Enter.

Comment: Would adding an event listener for pressing the 'Enter'-key be an option?

Comment: Have you solved it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to solve this on your Codesandbox by removing the `{...rest}` props spread you were applying in the SimpleInput component. This added some funky attributes that seemed to be interfering with the standard form field behavior.

You can see the proper submit-on-enter behavior here: https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-star-r0liq

In my own code, I am using a standard HTML `<form>` instead of the Formik `<Form>`, so when I ran into this issue, I had to ensure my submit button had both `type="submit"` attribute, as well as the `onClick` handler hooked up to Formik's `handleSubmit` method. Then the submit-on-enter behavior started working.

`<button 
    onClick={formProps.handleSubmit} 
    type="submit"
/>`

Related official repo issue: https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/1418

Comment: Yup, this was a while ago but I remember now, removing the `{...rest}` props from the input is exactly the solution that we (well, one of my then-colleagues) found.

Comment: FYI, this causes the form to be submitted twice

Answer (score 6):

The best way that I found to solve this scenery is to call handleSubmit() method inside onKeyDown event of HTML Form Element that is child of Formik.

```
      <Formik
        initialValues={{
          login: '',
          senha: ''
        }}
        onSubmit={(values, { setErrors }) => {
          this.submitSignin(values, setErrors);
        }}
      >
        {props => {
          const {
            values,
            handleChange,
            handleBlur,
            handleSubmit,
          } = props;
          return (
            <form 
              onSubmit={handleSubmit} 
              onKeyDown={(e) => {
                if (e.key === 'Enter') {
                  handleSubmit();
                }
              }}>
             <input 
               id="login"
               value={values.login}
               onChange={handleChange}
               onBlur={handleBlur} />
             <input 
               id="senha"
               value={values.senha}
               onChange={handleChange}
               onBlur={handleBlur} />
            </form>
          }
        </Formik>
```

Comment: Jared Palmer (Formik creator) advises against this: ["Generally tho, you should not implement onKeyPress"](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/1418#issuecomment-483657274)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try using the children prop with Formik as shown here: https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#children-reactreactnode-props-formikprops-values-reactnode

And remove the form element wrapping the form. Or disable the default behavior of the form. That's what's intercepting the enter keypress behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You will run into this problem if you [incorrectly pass all props](https://www.karltarvas.com/2022/09/16/formik-custom-input-not-submitting-on-enter.html) straight through to the custom component. As demonstrated [in the docs](https://formik.org/docs/api/field#component), you must remove the `form` props before passing the rest on to the custom component.

Shortly put, this is incorrect:

```
const CustomInput = (props: React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> & FieldProps) => {
  return <input {...props} />;
};
```

And this is correct:

```
const CustomInput = (props: React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> & FieldProps) => {
  const { form, field, ...rest } = props;
  return <input {...field} {...rest} />;
};
```